# GPO to Set Wallpaper per Computer instead of per User

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I'd like to be able to configure a GPO to set wallpapers computer rather than per user. However, reading through documentation and forums I've not been able to figure out what seems like it should be a simple thing to do.

This is for a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve here? Setting wallpaper on a 'per user' basis for all users should achieve the same affect as setting wallpaper for each computer would.

Comment: It would but I don't want the wallpapers to be set when people login to their laptops, only when they login to shared workstations. I can set the wallpaper locally on those workstations but I was trying to do this at the GPO level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to do this ("this" being "setting something in user policy based on which computer the user logged into") is [Loopback Processing](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287), where (in merge mode) the computer object's linked GPOs are checked for user policy as well as the user object.

Loopback processing can add a whole lot of complexity to your GPO environment and a lot unintended policies being applied - make sure you fully understand what it's going to do and test the potential impacts before you enable it.

Comment: If this is the case then it's really not worth it just to set a wallpaper on a per computer basis. I'll leave this open for a bit and barring any better answers give your the Check appropriately. Thanks Shane.

Comment: It's not extremely complex. If you add a single policy (this is your case) to your GPO and you set up loopback merge, it will do the job just fine.

Comment: @CharlieWilson In a clean environment, yes - but in most environments I've seen, there's some mess of GPOs linked to the OU the computer object is in which probably have user settings (due to linking in user OUs or accidental policies built in the wrong tree when the policy was being built) that would suddenly apply (with overriding priority over the user container's linked GPOs, potentially reversing security controls!) if loopback merge was turned on. That's the reason for the warning.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Objection your honor, speculative!
I understand your point, but he's asking for a solution to that particular problem, which you answered to. Whether or not he'll need to re-architecture his GPO is not relevant to this particular question.

Comment: @CharlieWilson Your argument seems to be that there must not be a "this is different than your standard GPO setting, understand before using" warning on a 2 yr old answer recommending loopback? Well, my answer is that the warning is staying. Loopback can have unpredictable effects (which I've cleaned up myself in several environments, and I mean *specifically loopback screwups* due to not understanding the feature), and a warning like that is justified any time applying one GPO will change the behavior of any other GPO, much less *every GPO applied to every computer the merge GPO lands on*.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is doable, there is no obvious way to do it because a **Wallpaper CANNOT be deployed to a "Computer" GPO... only to a "User" GPO**

This is how I did it, Crete and edit a new GPO and go to:
**User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Desktop\Desktop**
Here you enable the "Desktop Wallpaper" option .....   and then type the location, in order to simplify things, you can deploy it here:
**C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\NewWallpaper.jpg**

Now, you also need to copy the wallpaper image locally, so, on that same GPO you are editing, go to:
**User Configuration\Preferences\Windows Settings\Files**
Then create a new "File" entry
**Action:** Replace
**Source file(s):**  \yourfileserverUNC\Share\NewWallpaper.jpg
**Destination File:** C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\NewWallpaper.jpg

Then you apply this GPO to the root of your Domain, I know you are now asking, how do I limit the GPO so it only runs on certain computers??.. that is the secret sauce my friend, WMI Filters !!!..  you can create a WMI filter that limits the execution of the GPO to a certain number of IP addresses, or a range of IP addresses, go to the WMI Filters section and create a new Filter of type "root\CIMv2" and on the "Query"field type:

**select * from Win32_IP4RouteTable where (Name like "10.1.3.%" OR Name like "10.122.77.29" OR Name like "10.122.77.30")**

Save the WMI Filter, then go back to the GPO and under the "Scope" tab you will see a WMI Filtering" option all the way at the bottom, select the WMI Filter you created, that will limit the execution of the GPO to those machines or range of machines specified by the IP Addresses.. it works really well on my systems..  I hope it helps.. Thanks!

Comment: Easy to setup, works perfectly fine but if you don't have a static IP, use this instead: select * from Win32_ComputerSystem where Name LIKE "COMPUTERNAME%"